# Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache

I am getting an error

"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@******.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

on trying to access my site. I even tried on a different server that was working properly and yet the same result. 
Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rename .htaccess file to something else and try to access which should be located at the site root url

Answer (score 1):

The `500 Internal Server Error` status code is normally caused by a misconfiguration in the web server or a server-side app that fails to work properly or is crashing. Find the web server error log: you should find the exact details of the error right there. In Apache, logs tend to be under `%ProgramFiles%\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs` (Windows) or `/var/log/httpd` (Linux).

The `404 Not Found` status code when using the `ErrorDocument` directive is exactly that: you've customized your "not found" page with a file that does not exist. Find such directive in your Apache settings and fix it accordingly.

Comment: /var/log/httpd was locked in my computer and I donot have permission to access it. Anyway my problem is solved. I had a file called .ftpquota in my folder. I just deleted the file and it started working. Can anyone give me an explanation? Thanks for all your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user556773 Given that in contains the `ftp` substring, it's hard to see why it can affect the behaviour of the `http` server... :-? Did you read the file contents before removing it?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are having problem in your server configuration. If you are using apache server then it might be problem in .htaccess file check if there is any .htaccess file exists in your root folder if it is remove it and check it again

Comment: I donot have a .htaccess file.

Comment: usually this file remail hidden

Comment: I have checked for hidden files also. It is not there in my folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is a permission issue
Setting a 777 permission on a directory can cause this error